# How to enable proxy using azure::storage?

Tags: proxy, azure-storage, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

azure::storage provides a class `operation_context` which has `set_proxy()` and `set_default_proxy()` methods. However, I could not find any info on how to use it.

For example, how do I make sure that a `cloud_blob_client` created afterwards will use the operation?

I'm assuming that the static version of the method (i.e. `set_default_proxy()`) will affect all instances of operation.

Will all `cloud_blob_client` instances use it?

Usage of `web::http::client::http_client` with proxy is more obvious. I can use the following code to configure the client with a proxy:

```
http_client_config config;
config.set_proxy(web_proxy(web_proxy::use_default));
http_client(uri, config);
```

Answer (score 0):

`set_default_proxy()` worked for me as long as `web_proxy` was configured with a proxy address.  That is, `web_proxy::use_default` and `web_proxy::use_discovery` did not work although I had proxy settings defined for current user on Windows.